# int * vs float * type

Tags: c, pointers, floating-point, assign

Given the following snippet of code:

```
int *iptr;
float *fptr;
float fval;
fval = 0.0;
fptr = &fval;
iptr = fptr;
printf("%d \n", *iptr);
fval = 1.0;
printf("%d \n", *iptr);
```

The output is:

> 0
>   1065353216

Why does the first print statement at least approximately match the value associated with *iptr (0.0), yet the second print statement doesn't?

Comment: Try `printf("%d", fval);`

Comment: Read up on the representation of float. Then you will understand.

Comment: A good beginner's reference for floating-point representation can be found here: http://floating-point-gui.de.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you write `printf("%d \n", *iptr);`, you are asking `printf` to interpret the value pointed to by `iptr` as an integer.

It just so happens that `float` version of `0` is represented by the same bits of the `int` version of `0`. In particular, the bits are all `0`.

However, an arbitrary float, such as `1.0` will have a different bit representation (as defined by IEEE Standards) which will make little sense when interpreted as an `int`.

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary32) explains how a float is represented as bits.

Comment: @merlin2011: is strict aliasing not an issue here? (e.g., here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule,  "So basically if you have an int* and a float* they are not allowed to point to the same memory location. If your code does not respect this, then the compiler's optimizer will most likely break your code."

Comment: @dmcr_code It definitely is. That's why I added my own answer.

Comment: @ajay: Yes, I think it has to be mentioned; (unfortunately) C has many "nasty" details which one needs to know(I myself got acquainted with some of them recently, like this one, or signed/unsigned mixing, etc.)

Comment: @dmcr_code Writing safe, standards compliant C code is far from a trivial task and requires serious effort. I myself am learning it the hard way.

Comment: @ajay: standards compliance is smth I haven't "considered" so far, I usually try to write with what I have learned (e.g., using books), and not reinvent the wheel and try to avoid some cryptic expressions, etc.  and watch for pitfalls like this one for example

Comment: @ajay, Thanks for supplementing this answer with your own. Strict aliasing is certainly an issue, but that was not the first thing that came to mind when I saw this question. :)

Answer (score 3):

The statement `iptr = fptr;` will invoke *undefined behaviour*.

There is not much point in speculating about the outcome therefore.

Comment: Why is it *Undefined Behavior*

Comment: Because you're effectively doing a cast to an unrelated pointer type.

Comment: @Bathsheba can you quote the relevant portion from the standard please, which explains this?

Comment: I'm in a coffee shop so can't. But it's rather like doing `(int*)(void*)(float*)&fval` which, we all know is UB.

Answer (score 3):

@merlin has explained the output of your code very nicely and clearly. However, there's more to it so I will add it here. Your code violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)  and invokes undefined behaviour.  Strict aliasing rule means different pointer types should not point to the same memory location.

```
iptr = fptr;
```

`iptr` is of type `int *` and `fptr` is of type `float *`. This statement assigns `fptr` to `iptr` - a different type - which means both now point to `fval`. This breaks the strict aliasing rule. This causes undefined behaviour which means unpredictable behaviour. The standard imposes no requirements on the implementation to deal which such cases. In short, you should avoid code which causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Its an undefined behavior: `iptr = fptr;`. You cannot print a float as an int, floats are stored in [IEEE754 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary32)

You need to try this:

```
printf("%d", fval);
```

Answer (score 1):

A zero floating point number consists of zeroes. Any other number is not just the number but an exponent and a mantissa - of course neither of them is just your number.

Answer (score 1):

Floats are stored in IEEE754 format, in which the value of a number such as 1.0 is quite different to 1 (it is offset to allow for negative numbers and exponents). You cannot print a float as an int and have the result resemble the number assigned to the float.